# Is there a word for people who are addicted to mechanical things?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

"mechanical things" includes mechanical watch, mechanical computer, automaton.

People of this type have one or more of the characters below:

- **Feel extremely satisfied when watching very complicated and precise mechanical internal structure working, like an inspection view of the inside of automaton or analytical engine.** (this is the most important one)
- Strongly prefer mechanical products over electronic ones in daily life, e.g. mechanical watch vs digital watch, hand crank charger vs common charger.
- Make or teardown mechanical gadgets as a hobby.
- Attracted by steampunk creations (like authors of [this site](https://steampunktendencies.com/)).

For disambiguation, characters below are not considered as meeting the definition:

- Addicted to mechanical keyboards.
- DIY generalist, or woodworkers.

Comment: Do you mean someone who prefers mechanical gadgets to electronic ones? Would they prefer purely mechanical to electro-mechanical ones? Would that restrict them to a Babbage Difference Engine or a Turing Bombe instead of a Mac or Windows PC?

Comment: Upvoting because I desperately want a word for the post-industrial "Luddite".

Comment: @Cascabel thanks for the suggestion, I just added some characters to explain the definition.

Comment: @BoldBen Yes; Yes; No; A "addicted to mechanical things" person like me do have huge interest in difference engine and other mechanical computers, but I still prefer to use modern computers for better efficiency :)

Comment: Your "most-important" criterion sounds a  little like _self-hypnotism_.

Answer (score 3):

According to Lexico, a *[propeller-head](https://www.lexico.com/definition/propeller-head)* is a person who has an obsessive interest in computers or technology

According to Collins such a person has no hyphen: *[propeller head](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/propeller-head)*.

Comment: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

**Gearhead** is the closest word I know, but it refers to people who are into cars. Maybe it would be close enough for your purposes.

Comment: It's close, but still very different. Like you said "gearhead" is specifically restricted to cars, cars is part of mechanical, but mechanical is not only about cars.

Answer (score 0):

https://writershelpingwriters.net/2014/04/talents-skills-thesaurus-entry-mechanically-minded/

**Mechanically Inclined:**

Mechanically inclined people are able to intuitively see how things work. Good with tools and machinery, they’re adept at fixing things and are often able to take unfamiliar items apart and…

Comment: Relevant, but OP specifies a single word / noun.

Comment: There may not be a one-word solution. Mechanical process enthusiast? :)

Comment: _Propellor-head_ fits.